# Assigning a property to an EF model so that an object knows it is ==max

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities

I have an EF model from which I select a sub-set of data to present in ASP.NET.  When I am presenting this output I loop through the returned objects.  I would like to know when I am presenting the object with the highest value (to format it differently).

```
ObjectTable
Category  Item Value
X         A    1.0
X         B    14.0
X         C    9.0
Y         D    18.0
```

I can return the items I want to view with:

```
var obj = from o in ObjectTable where Category=="X" select o;
```

I want to know that B has the highest value.

I am very flexible with how this happens I just haven't been able to come up with a sensible solution.  Should I modify the LINQ statement to add a LET statement creating an obj.IsMax variable and if o.Value==o.Max make it TRUE and all other objects as FALSE, if so how?  This route seems like it would be expensive?

Or could I extend the EF Model with a partial class and somehow calculate whether the model value is equal to the max value of the returned objects?

Or something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj  = (ObjectTable.Where(o => o.Category == "Y"));
var anonymousObjList = obj.Select(o => new {o, IsMax = (o.Value == obj.Max(x => x.Value))});
```

And looping thru anonymousObjList

```
foreach(var obj in anonymousObjList)
{
    var actualObject = obj.o;
    var isMax = obj.IsMax;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Sorry just realised there was a typo in my example which makes it less clear.  I will adjust and explain

Comment: IsMax in your example is comparing to the maximum of all values in the table, not just the values in the category returned by the query, which is what I require